# How to overload strings in perl

Tags: string, perl, overloading

I was trying to overload classes to strings in perl. For example:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class overloadingInPerl{
    use overload '""' => sub {shift->printOut()};


    method printOut(){
       return "Overloading worked";
    }
}


my $overloadingTrial = overloadingInPerl->new();
print $overloadingTrial;
```

prints out: overloadingInPerl=HASH(0x1f520fc)

want to print: Overloading worked

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You have to add the dirty trait](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/MooseX-Declare-0.35/lib/MooseX/Declare.pm#clean) to use overloading

```
class overloadingInPerl is dirty {
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than adding the `dirty` trait, as pointed by @oylenshpeegul you can also drop the coderef calling the actual function by passing its name as string and removing the () from the method declaration.

Errrm, easier showed than said.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                               
use Test::More tests=>1;                                                          
use MooseX::Declare;                                                              
class C is dirty {                                                                
    use overload '""' => 'to_string';                                             
    method to_string { sprintf "#<%s data='%s'>", $self->meta->name, $self->data }
    has data => (is=>'rw',default=>'');                                           
}                                                                                 
is(C->new(data=>'hello'), "#<C data='hello'>");
```